# Почему при отправки формы в адресе появляется #wpcf7-f606-o1?

Tags: wordpress

Я использую плагин Contact Form 7. Когда я нажимаю кнопку «Отправить», URL-адрес выглядит так, как указано выше. Что это за #wpcf7-f606-o1?

URL-адрес выглядит так:  https://url.com/#wpcf7-f903-o1  для отправки  формы использую метод post

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/, https://contactform7.com/faq/after-submission-my-contact-form-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

нашла праблему, дело в том что я не написала на footer.php wp_footer() после того как написала  форма начала  работать корректно